# Capture text between SGM tags using REGEX

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use a regular expresion to capture the text between the last `</tabmat>` tag and last `</para>` tag. I tried using `</tgroup></tbody></tabmat>.*?</para>` or `(<tabmat frame=".*?".*?>(?:[\s\S](?!<\/tabmat))+?Input Conditions[\s\S]+?)[</tabmat>]*(?=</para>)` but that hasn't worked. It selects all the text in between the first tabmat tag and continues to the end of the first `</para` tag. If you look at the XML test example, a `<warning` tag is opened and has multiple `<para` tags. The regex selects the text up to the first `</para` tag. but doesn't capture the last `</para`.

Example:
`</tbody></tgroup></tabmat>End Text</para>`

REGEX:
`(<tabmat frame=".*?".*?>(?:[\s\S](?!<\/tabmat))+?Input Conditions[\s\S]+?)[</tabmat>]*(?=</para>)`

I can't figure out what REGEX I should use. Your help is appreciated.

Example XML:

```
<tabmat frame="none" colsep="0" pgwide="0">
<tgroup cols="2" align="left">
<colspec colname="col1" align="left" colwidth="0.99in">
<colspec colname="col2" colwidth="0.78*">
<spanspec namest="col1" nameend="col2" spanname="span1">
<tbody>
<row>
<entry spanname="span1" colsep="0" align="left">
<emphasis type="u"> Input Conditions</emphasis>.</entry></row></tbody></tgroup></tabmat>
<tabmat frame="none" colsep="0" pgwide="0">
<tgroup cols="2" align="left">
<colspec colname="col1" align="left" colwidth="1.0in">
<colspec colname="col2" colwidth="0.78*">
<spanspec namest="col1" nameend="col2" spanname="span1">
<tbody>
<row>
<entry spanname="span1" colsep="1" align="left">
<emphasis type="b">Applicability: </emphasis> All</entry></row></tbody></tgroup></tabmat>
<tabmat frame="none" colsep="0" pgwide="0">
<tgroup cols="1">
<colspec colname="col1" colwidth="1.00*">
<tbody>
<row>
<entry>
<emphasis type="b">Required Conditions:</emphasis></entry></row>
<row valign="top">
<entry>
<randlist>
<item>r  oGiyelC rfreSponguiVdyeps rd (reef rt o<emphasis type="u" color="blue">
<xref xref="test ref"></emphasis>).</item>
<item> ScfChosmer kC Geot nsuren ono ctiawdt ill n soexisipvrtt e hnethe  nctneqeucarnttaeironedi am inogmfr p ibereofmrde.</item>
<item>erh prossa  nipEsvunvbla rieaaetaxle eitinaedthte er gfn inumia .aecenist </item></randlist></entry></row></tbody></tgroup></tabmat>
<tabmat frame="none" colsep="0" pgwide="0">
<tgroup cols="1">
<colspec colname="col1" colwidth="1.00*">
<tbody>
<row>
<entry>
<emphasis type="b">Personnel Recommended:</emphasis> 2 </entry></row>
<row>
<entry>
<randlist>
<item>cihTnieca  enAprformGs Ca oSprteoirnnuo fct</item>
<item>teisTchncsii eca TBnnsaihsa inc A</item></randlist></entry></row></tbody></tgroup></tabmat>
<tabmat frame="none" colsep="0" pgwide="0">
<tgroup cols="2">
<colspec colname="colspec0" align="left">
<colspec colname="colspec1">
<spanspec namest="colspec0" nameend="colspec1" spanname="span1">
<tbody>
<row>
<entry spanname="span1" colsep="1" align="left">
<emphasis type="b">Support Equipment:</emphasis> None</entry></row></tbody></tgroup></tabmat>
<tabmat frame="none" colsep="0" pgwide="0">
<tgroup cols="2">
<colspec colname="colspec0" align="left">
<colspec colname="colspec1">
<spanspec namest="colspec0" nameend="colspec1" spanname="span1">
<tbody>
<row>
<entry spanname="span1" colsep="1" align="left">
<emphasis type="b">Consumables: </emphasis> None</entry></row></tbody></tgroup></tabmat>
<tabmat frame="none" pgwide="0">
<tgroup cols="1">
<colspec colname="col1">
<tbody>
<row>
<entry>
<emphasis type="b">Safety Conditions:</emphasis>
<warning>
<para>ctdesajTehu inshsevtetnarroorohfedln yl crt . oswoi uano ipko .reuFacg.ielat   drzetod tl ciT  inedcuseer uc lori epiu elyosyloif mropsh,l  sonawart elmr o eccoaolhrimmc edzhpu orodmpnyennhatsd a rn neeergi</para>
<para>ePfrrom pproer <acronym><def>Oto  Luk cTt ag uO</def><term>OLTO</term></acronym>yn  ncsaerse oictrbsr er ueicoakr <acronym>
<def>Emergecny oP ewrOff</def><term>EPO</term></acronym>rc pew ricsploihe npct lcdcioba.uaadehatn rscel a lwi</para><para> rnieidoFoa.to o tpalnueenyengstp ecm rsiorulol  oro cee qeod tdrtrydeacma ero /nirlcac  ursenlsnpdeoalr howpgtnirtr nre  upprori etf mm onoiena rtmii vjauaitellsat</para></warning></entry></row></tbody></tgroup></tabmat>TEST</para>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl regexp tested on your sample in UE 28.20.0.70

```
(?s).*</tabmat>\K.*(?=</para>)
```